# Using Array as a Dynamic JQuery String Variable Name

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, select, dynamic

Summary: I have passed the name of the id select tag into an Array. I want to dynamically assign each Select Item to display the Index of the selected item upon change. This is sent to the output div. Only the third select item is dynamically being triggered. Why?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var NameOfSelect=new Array("a","b","c");

for (i=0;i<NameOfSelect.length;i++){

var sel=NameOfSelect[i];
$("#"+NameOfSelect[i]).change(function () {
           var str = "";
           $("#"+sel+" option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).index() + " "+$("#"+sel).attr("id");
                  });
          $("#output").text(str);
       })
        .trigger('change');

}
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<select id="a" >
<option value="0a" >0a</option>
<option value="1a"  >1a</option>
<option value="2a" >2a</option>

</select>


<select id="b" >
<option value="0b"  >0b</option>  
<option value="1b" >1b</option>
<option value="2b" >2b</option>
</select>

<select id="c" >
<option value="0c" >0c</option>
<option value="1c" >1c</option>
<option value="2c" >2c</option>

</select>
<div id=output></div>
```

The output shows that only "C" is being triggered on change.
Why are "a" and "b" not being similarly dynamically assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the variable `c` gets reassigned with every iteration. At the end of the for-loop, all elements will have a proper event handler, but they will refer to the same `c` variable inside their function body. This variable will be holding the last value of `c`, being `"c"`.

One solution would be to cache the value of `c` in a closure for every function handler you assign, but in this case it's much better to simply use `this` inside the handler to refer to the `select` element that was targeted by the `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var NameOfSelect = ["a", "b", "c"];

    for (var i=0; i < NameOfSelect.length; i++) {
        $("#"+NameOfSelect[i]).change(function () {
            // this refers to the targeted select element
            var select = this;
            var str = "";
            $("option:selected", this).each(function () {
                // this refers to the selected option
                str += $(this).index() + " " + $(select).attr("id");
            });
            $("#output").text(str);
        }).trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Also, unless you're using `select`s with multiple selections, there should only be one `option:selected` for each `select` element. Therefore, you could just use `find` and work with the first (and only) selected `option`.

```
var str = $("option:selected", this).index() + " " + $(this).attr("id");
$("#output").text(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Good ol' javascript closure issue, I believe.  The function you assign to the change event references the variable c, which changes for each iteration of the for loop and ends as 'c'.  Instead, pass c into the function:

```
var c= NameOfSelect[i];
(function (n) {
    $("#"+NameOfSelect[i]).change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("#"+n+" option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).index() + " "+$("#"+n).attr("id");
        });

        $("#output").text(str);
    }).trigger('change')
})(c);
```